# Adding flex-direction: column causes elements to vanish

Tags: css, flexbox

It's my first time using flex-box. I am following a tutorial where this very example works.

I have 3 colo(u)red `div`s, side by side as is the default for flex-box, apparently.

When I add `flex-direction: column;` to the container of the `div`s, they no longer display (for me, although they do in the tutorial video).

I have prepared [a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeKdWTfFI7S2CMAa?open=lib%2Fscript.js).  Just uncomment  `/*flex-direction: column;*/` to see my problem; here's the full code too.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**index.html**
<!doctype html>

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <section id="container">
      <div id="child_1" class="child"></div>
      <div id="child_2" class="child"></div>
      <div id="child_3" class="child"></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#container{
  display: flex;  /* use flex-box */
  width: 100%;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

.child{
  /*width: 200px;*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  flex: 1;  /* all available width (will be shared) */
}

#child_1{
  /*height: 150px;*/
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 2;  /* twice as wide as the others */
}

#child_2{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child_3{
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: `flex: 2;` and `flex: 1;` are messing up with your heights because it will set the `flex-basis` to `0%`. You could use `flex: 2 0 auto` or `flex-grow: 2` instead.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) pls, `flex: ...`

Comment: `Flex:1` in a column does **NOT** relate to width

Comment: @AmauryHanser feel free to post that as an answer. `Flex-grow` instead of just `flex` did the trick! Update - and working - Plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeKdWTfFI7S2CMAa?open=lib%2Fscript.js). I guess thigs have changed since the tutorial video was recorded.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `flex: 1;` and `flex: 2;` are messing with your heights. There is a reason for that:

> in case both flex-basis (other than auto) and width (or height in case of flex-direction: column) are set for an element, flex-basis has priority.

Source: [MDN - flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

You could get rid of them, change them to `flex-grow` or change the `flex-basis` to see the div back.

```css
#container{
  display: flex;  /* use flex-box */
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child{
  /*width: 200px;*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;  /* all available width (will be shared) */
}

#child_1{
  /*height: 150px;*/
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 2;  /* twice as wide as the others */
}

#child_2{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child_3{
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<section id="container">
  <div id="child_1" class="child"></div>
  <div id="child_2" class="child"></div>
  <div id="child_3" class="child"></div>
</section>
```